# XamlReader.Load() Marshalled

Tags: c#, c++, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to generate my own custom tile from xaml. I've converted some code from C++ to C# in order to integrate it into my app.

Basically I've got this method:

```
async Task GenerateHighResTileImage(string inputMarkupFilename, string outputImageFilename, Size size)
{
     StorageFolder assetsFolder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
     StorageFile markupStorageFile = await assetsFolder.GetFileAsync(inputMarkupFilename);
     string markupContent = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(markupStorageFile);

     Border grid = (Border)XamlReader.Load(markupContent);
     await RenderAndSaveToFileAsync(grid, outputImageFilename, (int)size.Width, (int)size.Height);
}
```

The debugger halts on the line where I'm trying to load the markup saying:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in
>   BGTask.winmd
>
> Additional information: The application called an interface that was
>   marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E
>   (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

My tile is very plain, as I'm just testing:

```
<Border Height="360" Width="360" Padding="12" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="2" Background="#00b2f0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
</Border>
```

And it is able to successfully load it in the markupContent string.

The code looks like this in C++

```
task<void> AppTileUpdater::GenerateHighResTileImageUpdateAsync(String^ inputMarkupFilename, String^ outputImageFilename, Size size)
{
    return create_task(Package::Current->InstalledLocation->GetFolderAsync("Assets"))
        .then([inputMarkupFilename](StorageFolder^ assetsFolder) ->IAsyncOperation<StorageFile^>^ {
        return assetsFolder->GetFileAsync(inputMarkupFilename);
    }).then([](StorageFile^ markupStorageFile)  ->IAsyncOperation<Platform::String^>^ {
        return FileIO::ReadTextAsync(markupStorageFile);
    }).then([this, outputImageFilename, size](Platform::String^ markupContent){
          Border^ border = (Border^) XamlReader::Load(markupContent);

          return RenderAndSaveToFileAsync(border, outputImageFilename, (unsigned int) size.Width, (unsigned int) size.Height);
    });
}
```

Am I missing something?

Edit
The method is being run from the **Run** method

```
async public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    taskInstance.Canceled += (s, e) => { };
    taskInstance.Progress = 0;

    await GenerateHighResTileImage("150x150Tile.xml", "updatedTile.png", new Size(150, 150));
    UpdateTile("updatedTile.png");

    deferral.Complete();

}
```

The code also works fine when I run it outside the BackgroundTask

Comment: From which method do you call the method `GenerateHighResTileImage`? Is the `SyncronizationContext.Current` not null at the start of the method `GenerateHighResTileImage`?.

Comment: I'm uncertain, Ill add the code

Comment: I don't familiar with Windows Phone threading model but, anyway, if you hasn't synchronization context then your continuation after await will be marshaled to the thread pool. Check the `SyncronizationContext.Current` at start of your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Silverlight, then you will need to run your code from the default dispatcher[`Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)`]. If you are using a Universal App, you need to derive from the [`XamlRenderingBackgroundTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.xamlrenderingbackgroundtask.aspx) but it is highly recommended you use C++ to avoid running out of memory.

Comment: And that's exactly all it took.